# Setting up a reverse proxy where the target server requests from the proxy

Tags: server, reverse-proxy

I know this sounds stupid, but let me explain. So my friend and I are setting up a server/website for our cs teacher. The problem is that the school internet blocks all requests to the server from outside of the network. My friend had the idea of setting up a server outside of the network and have it recieve the requests, and then have the actual server send get requests to see if there is traffic and post requests to send back information. I know that also sounds stupid but our cs teacher wants us to set up the server inside his classroom. Is there any way to do this, this is really easy to do, or if I'm going to have to make the system myself?

I think that there wouldn't be a way to do this already as it's kind of a stupid idea but maybe there is so i'm asking just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be worth seeing if you can use ngrok or cloudflare tunnels to expose the server externally.

These basically do exactly what you are asking, and you will be able to access the site outside as if it was published.

However, I suspect this might be against your schools policies and could get you in trouble. It's worth checking that out.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out. if it works I'll mark this as accepted.